Email Sending getting timed out
This is my python code which I m using to send email to Gmail using SMTP
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

subject = "Email Subject"
body = "This is the body of the text message"
sender = '#####@gmail.com'
recipients = '####@gmail.com'
password = '######'  # Note: App password for 2FA



def send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients, password):
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    try:
       with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) as smtp_server:
            smtp_server.ehlo()
            smtp_server.starttls()
            smtp_server.login(sender, password)
            smtp_server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
            print("Message sent!")
    except:
        print("Unable to send email")


send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients, password)

The operation is getting timed out

Need pointers if I m doing something wrong
I m referring this -https://mailtrap.io/blog/python-send-email-gmail/
